# Moving Single Directory Repository into Trunk, Branch, Tag Directories

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I currently have

```
MyRepositories
|-- ThisRogueRepository
|   |-- app
```

I want:

```
MyRepositories
|-- ThisRogueRepository
|    |-- branch
|    |-- trunk
|    |   |-- app
|    |-- tag
```

where app is my current app directory, with all of it's revision history intact.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want it to be `branches`, `trunk` and `tags`. That's the normal convention. Create these folders first ( you can do so from Repobrowser). Still in Repo Browser, select move on the app and select the trunk path and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Just use TortoiseSVN's repo browser to create the new directories and then move the app directory to trunk.